# redirect to different controller dependant on Url

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok so I'm trying to redirect the request to a different controller depending on the URL.

My `server.js` :

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express();

var router = express.Router();

// controllers
var { loginController } = require('./controller/loginController');

// Specify routes
app.use('/test', loginController);


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('started on port 3000');
});

module.exports = { app }
```

Now if the URL is /test then I would like to redirect the request to `loginController`, inside `loginController` I have the following:

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('inside logincontroller');
});
```

Very short and sweet, however when I run `node server.js` I get the following error message: `Router.use() requires middleware function but got a undefined`  now I've gone through the [Router Use](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.use) but I'm slightly confused (newbie) I don't have any middleware at present.

Would someone be able to explain to me how I go about redirecting the request to the `loginController` when the url is `/test`

Comment: You forgot to export `router` in loginController

Comment: Initialization of `loginController` on line 5 is unknown to me. Trying `var { a } = 1;` assigns `undefined` to the variable `a` for me.

Comment: @CarmeloCatalfamo still same error after exporting router

Comment: @CodeRatchet I will send you an answer with an example of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server.js

```
const express = require('express')

// Controllers
var loginController = require('./controller/loginController')

var app = express()

// Specify routes
app.use('/test', loginController)

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('started on port 3000')
})
```

loginController.js

```
const express = require('express')

var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('inside logincontroller')
})

module.exports = router
```

Then if you visit `http://localhost:3000/test` will get the output 'inside logincontroller'